# Select a row and column from a query in coldfusion 10

Tags: coldfusion

Can I select a certain row/column combination in coldfusion without doing a query of queries? For example:

```
Some Query: 

    ValueToFind    |  ValueToReturn  
    String 1       |  false
    String 2       |  false
    String 3       |  true
```

Can I somehow do `#SomeQuery["ValueToFind=String 3"][ValueToReturn]# = true` without doing a query of queries ? I know there's code out there to get a certain row by id, but I'm not sure how or if I can do it when I need a string as the ID

If this can't be done, is there a short hand way to set up a coldfusion function so I can use something like FindValue(Query, "String 3") and not have to use   ?

Comment: What if the value you seeks appears more than once?

Comment: Honestly it hadn't occurred to me. I can make sure in the query this doesn't happen though.

Comment: Do you actually need the row number, or just verify it exists? If it is the latter, and you need to do frequent look ups, might consider using a structure, which is better suited for "look ups".

Comment: The way it's set up, I do need the row number. However, I can eliminate all the falses beforehand...

Comment: Actually that would work too. Just make the row number the structure "value", and the string to find the "key".

Comment: .. though looking at the comments, it is less ideal if you need to search multiple columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can treat a query column as an array.

```
yourRow = ArrayFind(queryName['columnName'], "'the value you seek'");
```

If you get a zero, `the value you seek`is not there.

**Edit starts here:**

For values of other columns in that row, simply use that variable.

```
yourOtherValue = queryName.otherColumnName[yourRow];
```

Comment: This gets me close; It gets me whether or not `ValueToFind` contains a value, but no values in corresponding columns of the same row.

Comment: @JamesAMohler, what's a member function?

Comment: Functions that are already build into certain data types like arrays. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/using-the-member-functions.html

Comment: ArrayFind is the only function I used, and it's listed in the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

A small modification to Dan's code, you can find the column value using the code below

```
yourVaue  = SomeQuery["ValueToReturn"][ArrayFind(SomeQuery['ValueToFind'], "String 3")]
```